# Javascript: cycle through the same property of several objects

Tags: javascript, object, for-loop

Sorry if this is a dumb question, but I'm kind of new to this. I have several objects (object1, object2, object3...) which each have the same properties (property1, property2, property3...) like this:

```
var object1 = {color: red, length: 1, width: 6};
var object2 = {color: blue, length: 4, width: 2};
var object3 = {color: green, length: 4, width: 5};
```

How can I make a `for` loop that runs through the same property of each object, instead of each property for one object?

Thank you!

Comment: nest loops. Think of it as a 2d array. Or use the map/reduce/filer abstractions depending on the needs.

Comment: you need a array of those objects or some kind of reference to those objects to go through

Comment: Check out [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) and [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Comment: Put those objects in an array (instead of multiple variables with numbered names), and use a simple `for … of` loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could iterate first the properties and than the objects in an array.

```js
var object1 = { color: 'red', length: 1, width: 6 },
    object2 = { color: 'blue', length: 4, width: 2 },
    object3 = { color: 'green', length: 4, width: 5 };

['color', 'length', 'width'].forEach(function (k) {
    [object1, object2, object3].forEach(function (o) {
        console.log(o[k]);
    });
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Note that if you know all object have same properties, you can replace the hardcoded properties with `Object.keys(object1)`

Comment: @juvian, but then, you could take a const array for the keys, no need to render the keys over and over.